# Model is not defined

Tags: python, flask, peewee, flask-peewee

I'm using Flask and Peewee to create models for `Users` and `Appointments`, and each of them have a `ForeignKeyField` referencing each other. The problem is, if I define one above the other, Flask will give me `x is not defined`.

For example:

```
class User(Model):
   appointments = ForeignKeyField(Appointment, related_name='appointments')

class Appointment(Model):
   with_doctor = ForeignKeyField(User, related_name='doctor')
```

This would return `'User' is not defined`. How am I able to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally don't define the foreign key on both sides of the relationship, especially when the relationship isn't a one-to-one.

You should also set the `related_name` to something that makes sense on the related model. `user.appointments` is probably a better name for accessing a `User`'s `Appointment`s than `user.doctor`.

```
class User(Model):
   pass

class Appointment(Model):
   with_doctor = ForeignKeyField(User, related_name='appointments')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define it as a string as far as i know:

```
class User(Model):
   appointments = ForeignKeyField("Appointment", related_name='appointments')

class Appointment(Model):
   with_doctor = ForeignKeyField(User, related_name='doctor')
```

if the declaration is before the creation, you have the option to write it as a string.

I'm not sure, i think that the bind is at runtime.

Comment: If I do that I get `TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class`.

Answer (score 0):

try some changes like this, an example for Names & Addresses :

```
class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    addresses = db.relationship('Address', backref='person', lazy='dynamic')

class Address(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    person_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.id'))
```

as far as i know, you should use `db.ForeignKey()` for a relationship like this ... `ForeignKeyField()` defined in django

Comment: This looks like SQLAlchemy, not Peewee.